# T-SQL wild card brings back no results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This returns 110 results:

```
select * 
from regions 
where sponsor like '%'
```

This returns zero results and should return 110 records:

```
declare @sponsor char(4)
set @sponsor = '%'

select * 
from regions 
where sponsor like @sponsor
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using a `CHAR(4)`, it means that when you do:

```
declare @sponsor char(4)
set @sponsor = '%'
```

The actual value of sponsor is `'%   '`. Either use `CHAR(1)` or `VARCHAR(4)`

Comment: Thank you so much, I would have starred at that all day and gotten nowhere. My brain is totally fried atm. I have been starring at the damn over verbose query for over a day now. Its 3 pages long. I think I'm just going to rewrite it because there are many more issues

Answer (score 4):

`char` types are padded with whitespace. Your second query is actually equivalent to this:

```
select * from regions where sponsor like '%   '
```

Make `@sponsor` a `char(1)` or a `varchar(4)`.